# Expression2.MakeObjectID doesn't return a value- how can I obtain the new object id?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-addins

The [`Expression2.MakeObjectID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte100.expression2.makeobjectid.aspx) method creates a debug object ID, just like right-clicking a value in the debugger and selecting 'Make Object ID.'

I would like to be able to get that ID (such as 1#, 2#, 3#) for the expression and display it. `Expression2.Name`, `.Type` and `.Value` do not return the ID.
[`Debugger5.ExecuteStatement(expression.Name)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee886480.aspx) prints the expression's value and ID to the command window but I don't know how to read from that window, and I'd rather not write in it. There has to be a way to evaluate a statement and have it return the result instead of printing it to a window.

Does anyone know what steps I might take next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! [Debugger.GetExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.debugger.getexpression.aspx) and [Debugger5.GetExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee886474.aspx) act differently.

If I reobtain the same expression using Debugger5, the `{1#}` is appended to the Expression.Value.